# Splitting string into minimum value of unique elements with excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a dataset in Excel 2013, and I'm having some difficulty achieving the correct formulas for what I'm seeking to do. I don't think it would be very difficult in Python which I'm more familiar with, but I have to use excel only and VBA I guess to create custom functions (no experience).

Essentially, I have one column featuring strings such as
"C1 C0B1 3B 5B 5F 10F " in each cell
Each element is broken up by a space, which is easy enough to separate out using space delineation. I now have my string broken up in individual cells as:
"C1" "C0B1" "3B" "5B" "5F" "10F"

What I'm seeking to do is automate a process in which I can obtain the minimums for the unique identifiers with values in front of them ex) for "B" I want to eliminate "5B" and for "F" I want to eliminate "10F", only retaining the lowest value.

I want each of these elements (minus the redundant ones) in their own cells broken up. Ideally I would have a table I can lookup to input identifiers such as "B", "F", and "C1", "C0B1" etc. Is there a simple way to achieve this in Excel?

Bonus: Is there a way to achieve this while maintaining the space delineation structure from the beginning? To make this more clear, with the example given above minus the redundancies, my desired output would be:
"C1" "C0B1" "3B" "(empty)" "5F" "(empty)"

My initial thought process would be to create an index for each identifier and to eliminate everything beyond the first, as the values are already sorted by value (always "5B" and then "10B"). I don't really know if this is the correct approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use VBA?

Comment: Also, if you are going to use this for a LOOKUP table, and you are going to inputting only partial identifiers as you show in your question, `B` and `F` would be partial identifiers, then you will need to think about your layout very carefully.  If you cannot use VBA, you will need "helper" columns and your solution may depend in part on the Excel Version you are using.  You need to provide more information. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide examples of your data output, and also what you have done so far.

Comment: I believe I would be able to use VBA to create a custom function, but I don't have any experience coding in it. I'm using excel 2013.

Comment: Although sometimes it happens, this is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop. If you are facile with Python, you should be able to work something up.  Why must you use Excel?  There are plenty of instances of folks integrating Excel and Python.

Comment: That was not my intention and you're absolutely correct, I did a poor job of explaining my specific problem. I'm attempting to use a VLOOKUP to match to see whether or not the 'identifier' is present more than once. =IF(FIND(VLOOKUP(B7, Uniques!$A$3:$A$13&"*", 1, 0), B7), VLOOKUP(B7, Uniques!$A$3:$A$13&"*", 1, 0), FALSE) I'm running into trouble with the wildcard modifier being applied to the reference table.

Comment: I was able to find a solution using this as a reference : https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?3431-How-Can-I-Use-a-Wild-Card-in-a-VLOOKUP-Table-Array